# ASP.NET Checkbox won't check with jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I am attempting to make my checkboxes in a GridView easier to check for the user. I have added some jQuery to make the `<td>` element clickable and  check the checkbox. That part works. The problem is, when the user clicks the actual checkbox it will not check. When I debug my code, it appears that the .is(":checked") is not returning correctly. Any help will be appreciated.

**My GridView ItemTemplate**

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-Width ="5%"
         ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-CssClass="chk" >
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:CheckBox id="chkBxPSelect" runat="server" />
     </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

I have also tried wrapping the checkbox in a label and also an anchor tag as well to no avail.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-Width ="5%"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-CssClass="chk" >
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <label style="display:block;">
           <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBxPSelect" runat="server" /> 
        </label>                                                                                                                                             
    </ItemTemplate>
```

**My jQuery**

```
$(".chk").click(function (e)
{
    var checkBox = $(this).find("input:checkbox:first");

    if (checkBox.is(":checked"))
    {
        checkBox.prop("checked", false);
    }
    else
    {
        checkBox.prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I have also tried adding a click to the checkbox itself. It always seems that checking to see if the checkbox is checked using `.is(":checked") does not report the correct state of the checkbox.

```
$('input[id$="chkBxPSelect"]').click(function ()
{
   if ($(this).is(":checked"))
   {
      $(this).prop("checked", false);
   }
   else
   {
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
   }
```

});

**AND**
I tried this too form a suggestion below.

```
$('input[id$="chkBxPSelect"]').click(function ()
{
  e.preventDefault();
    //e.stopPropagation();

});
```

and still the checkbox won't check when clicking the actual checkbox.

Comment: Is ".chk" your checkbox class? if so, why are you trying to find another checkbox?, using $(this) should give you the actual instance (the checkbox clicked) then you can get it's value by usin $(this).val()

Comment: What is this class ".chk" ?

Comment: .chk is the class I added to the ItemTemplate. It is in the code above. I use it in the CSS to change the cursor to a pointer and also for jQuery to access the rendered `<td>` element. The checkboxes are in a GridView.

Comment: You probably need to add a click handler to the checkbox as well, and do e.preventDefault() or e.stopPropagation(). It sounds like the click in the checkbox is working, but is bubbling up to the td element, which is then reversing the check action on the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work:

```
$(".chk").click(function (e)
{
    var checkBox = $(this).find("input:checkbox:first");
    if (checkBox.is(":checked"))
    {
        checkBox.prop("checked", false);
    }
    else
    {
        checkBox.prop("checked", true);
    }
});

$(".chk input[type=checkbox]:first").click(function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I am not sure whether you need `preventDefault` or `stopPropagation`, but I believe it is `stopPropagation` to prevent the checkbox `click` from bubbling up to its parent `td`.

Another possible solution would be this. If it works I would recommend it, because it doesn't require any script:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-Width ="5%"
        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-CssClass="chk" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <label style="display:block;">
            <asp:CheckBox id="chkBxPSelect" runat="server" />
        </label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

When a checkbox is wrapped inside a `<label>` element, clicking anything inside of that label will toggle the checkbox's checked state. By giving the label a display:block style, this *should* make it take up the entire space of the table cell (td) that it is inside of. So, clicking anywhere in the td should in threory toggle the checkbox.

Comment: I tried both and neither worked. The selector seems good but as I stated above ( in my edited question) the .is(":checked") isn't reporting the proper state of the checkbox whether it be checked or not.

Comment: I answered my own question with your help. You certainly put me on the right track so you get the credit. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:  You could accomplish your task in this manner then:

```
<td class="Validate">
     <asp:Checkbox id="chkSelect" runat="server" class="chkSelect" ... />
</td>
```

By adding the class element, it will give the jQuery something to anchor on.  Then you could do:

```
$('.Validate').click(function () {
     var item = $(this).find('.chkSelect');
     if(item.is(':checked') {
         item.prop('checked', false);
     } else {
         item.prop('checked', true);
     }
});
```

So when you click your `td` the jQuery will execute, as for finding your input, you gave it a class identifier which mirrors your Id.  So, you use `find` to search the child elements within the `td element`.  This should find your input, then you simply do your check with the `var` that identified the checkbox.

---

You could in essence do the following, which will ensure your control is grabbed.

```
$('#<%= chkBxPSelect.ClientID %>').click(function () {
     if($(this).is(':checked')) {
         $(this).prop('checked', false);
     } else {
         $(this).prop('checked', true);
     }
});
```

If the `$(this)` doesn't work use the full identifier as noted above, but that Microsoft evaluation should resolve your issue.  Your other approach in JavaScript would be:

```
$(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:first');
```

I believe that should do the trick also.  You may want to test it, but I would use the first approach with Web-Forms.

Comment: I am actually trying to make the rendered `<td>` element clickable. Not sure why the `<td>` didn't show in my original question but I have edited it. Also, I am using a script file so .ClientID won't work. I can move it to the .aspx page if necassary though.

Comment: @Trucktech Try my updated answer, since your trying to use a `td` which I didn't see when I answered.

Answer (score 0):

I have this figured out with the help of @danludwig. 
I needed to add a click handler to the checkbox itself AND and e.stopPropagation() to prevent the event from bubbling up to the td. I also had to wrap the checkbox in a label tag and add a CssClass to the checkbox to make selecting it easier.

**My new checkbox.**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-Width ="5%"
        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-CssClass="chk">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <label style="display:block;">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBxPSelect" runat="server" CssClass="chkBox" />
        </label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**My new jQuery methods:**

```
$(".chk").click(function (e)
{

    var checkBox = $(this).children("input:checkbox:first");


    if (checkBox.is(":checked"))
    {
        checkBox.prop("checked", false);
    }
    else
    {
        checkBox.prop("checked", true);
    }    

});



$(".chkBox").click(function (e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();

    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
    }

});
```

Comment: You should use `find` rather than `children`.  `children` only goes on layer deep, where `find` will search all elements.  Web-Forms may generate more elements that your unaware of which may cause it not to work.

Comment: Per the docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/children/) . "Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector." So it actually gets ALL the children unless you specify a filter. The selector I specified `input:checkbox:first` will get the first input that is a checkbox and place it in my object.  This part has always worked anyway. It was just checking the actual checkbox and not the `<td>` that was giving me fits. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It only gets one level though, so it will get all root level children. If you need to go deeper, you require find.

Answer (score 0):

I just used z-index in style and works for me:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="txtNews" runat="server" style="z-index:9999;">
```